# On Stack Overflow for Teams, are votes undone when users leave?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

On regular Stack Exchange websites, if a user is deleted, their votes are undone.

Is the same true for Stack Overflow for Teams?  On a team site I'm part of, I've never seen a reputation change due to deleted users, but perhaps users that were deleted simply didn't vote on any of my posts.

Comment: I don't believe users are deleted when they "leave" the team. Users "remain", although no longer active. You can't really delete them without asking staff intervention.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

On a team site I'm part of, I've seen the reputation history of another user, who happens to be much more active than me (in particular in the past).  Their reputation history shows several events of reputation loss due to users being removed.